Lua Pandoc Citation Modifier
I'm trying to create a lua script that does the following with pandoc and its internal citeproc:
The current input is: (MPD; [@Somereference2020 noparens])
The desired output is: (MPD; Somereference, 2020) with the correct internal link to citeproc references.
I'm close, but I can't seem to wrangle removing the preceding space before noparens on the output.
Current output is: (MPD; Somereference, 2020 )
Note the space after the year which I've been able to debug to being the preceding space before the noparens (based on the debug output with carrots).
Thanks in advance to the Lua ninja ... Here's the code
function Cite(cite)
    for i, citation in ipairs(cite.citations) do
        if citation.suffix and pandoc.utils.stringify(citation.suffix):match("noparens") then
            -- Debugging: Print the original suffix
            print("Original suffix:", pandoc.utils.stringify(citation.suffix))

            -- Remove 'noparens' from the suffix
            local new_suffix = pandoc.List{}
            for _, item in ipairs(citation.suffix) do
                if item.t == "Str" then
                    -- Remove 'noparens' and trim spaces/commas
                    item.text = item.text:gsub("noparens", ""):gsub("^%s*,%s*", ""):gsub("%s*,%s*$", "")
                    if item.text ~= "" then
                        new_suffix:insert(item)
                    end
                else
                    new_suffix:insert(item)
                end
            end
            citation.suffix = new_suffix

            -- Debugging: Print the modified suffix
            print("Modified suffix:", pandoc.utils.stringify(citation.suffix))

            -- Debugging: Print the original content
            print("Original content:", pandoc.utils.stringify(cite.content))

            -- Remove 'noparens' and unnecessary parentheses from the content
            local new_content = pandoc.List{}
            for _, item in ipairs(cite.content) do
                if item.t == "Str" then
                    -- Remove 'noparens' and parentheses
                    item.text = item.text:gsub("noparens", ""):gsub("%(", ""):gsub("%)", ""):gsub("^%s*,%s*", ""):gsub("%s*,%s*$", "")
                end
                if item.text ~= "" then
                    new_content:insert(item)
                end
            end
            cite.content = new_content

            -- Debugging: Print the modified content
            print("Modified citation: ^" .. pandoc.utils.stringify(cite) .. "^")

            return cite
        end
    end
end

------- SOLUTION -----------
function Cite(cite)
    for i, citation in ipairs(cite.citations) do
        if citation.suffix and pandoc.utils.stringify(citation.suffix):match("noparens") then
            -- Debugging: Print the modified suffix
            -- print("Modified suffix:", pandoc.utils.stringify(citation.suffix))

            -- Debugging: Print the original content
            -- print("Original content:", pandoc.utils.stringify(cite.content))

            -- Remove 'noparens' and unnecessary parentheses from the content
            local new_content = pandoc.List{}
            for _, item in ipairs(cite.content) do
                if item.t == "Str" then
                    -- Remove 'noparens' and parentheses
                    item.text = item.text:gsub("noparens", ""):gsub("%(", ""):gsub("%)", ""):gsub("^%s*,%s*", ""):gsub("%s*,%s*$", "")
                    if item.text ~= "" then
                        new_content:insert(item)
                    end
                elseif item.t == "Link" then
                    -- Keep Link items
                    new_content:insert(item)
                end
                -- Space items are not added to new_content, effectively removing them
            end
            cite.content = new_content

            -- Debugging: Print the modified content
            -- print("Modified citation: ^" .. pandoc.utils.stringify(cite) .. "^")

            return cite
        end
    end
end

